# How do I Convert from Anonymous Event Handlers in C# to VB.Net

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, c#-to-vb.net

I have the below example code for a Windows Phone 7 application, and I am trying to convert it to VB.Net as a starting point. The assignments like this:

```
Loaded += (_, __) => { anonymousMethodBody();}
```

are failing to convert when I use a C#-to-VB conversion tool. How should those be translated?

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Loaded += (_, __) =>
        {
            PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
            cam = new VideoCamera();
            cam.Initialized += (___, ____) =>
                {
                    cam.LampEnabled = true;
                    cam.StartRecording();
                };
            vCam.SetSource(cam);

            new Thread(() =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

                        var files = isf.GetFileNames();
                        foreach (var file in files)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine("Deleting... " + file);
                            isf.DeleteFile(file);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Error cleaning up isolated storage: " + ex);
                    }
                }).Start();
        };
}
```

Comment: Which errors are you getting?

Comment: errors regarding the methods that look similar to += (___, ____) =>

Comment: Your lambdas' naming convention makes my eyes bleeding.

Comment: Since this is your second "how do I convert from C# to VB" question, it might make sense for you to start looking through tutorials, etc and try to start actually understanding C#.

Comment: I suspect that this is pretty opaque C# to someone new to the language. Decompiling with one of the open source reflection tools might have made clearer what is going on though.

Comment: @abatishchev Its not my code, thats why I need help

Comment: += (___, ____) =>  That's not code, that's my neighbor's rear end shot with an arrow.

Comment: I have to consider the opposite position from the consensus that the ignored lambda parameters should have any more meaningful name than the underscores... Since they are being explicitly ignored, that style has the arguable merit that the eye skims right past them. If you ever reference them, they need better names, but source, eventargs when both are ignored could be.... ignored.

Answer (score 3):

The `Loaded` event handler is defined in the C# code you posted using a lambda expression. I suppose most VB.NET-C# converters don't handle those very well, since they are relatively new. Try this:

```
AddHandler Loaded, Sub() 'Pass the Loaded event parameters, I cannot see them in your code
                  'The code inside the big block
                   End Sub
```

You don't need to call `RemoveHandler` (read comments below).

Comment: You would not remove the event handler listener.

Comment: @Tetsujin no Oni: Shouldn't it be removed on `Dispose`?

Comment: There's no evidence that the object in question implements IDisposable; PhoneApplicationPage doesn't appear to have it in its inheritance tree from my examination of the framework documentation... 

For cases as the discussion on the other page where you want to start and stop responding to events, then you definitely wouldn't use this pattern, but anonymous delegates for full-lifecycle event handlers seems a natural enough choice.

Comment: That's very true. Updated answer.