# C# event += delegate {} equivalent in VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, delegates, equivalent

Well, I was translating a `C# into VB.NET` using [developer fusion](http://developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/), and the API didn't translated me that part...

```
owner.IsVisibleChanged += delegate
            {
                if (owner.IsVisible)
                {
                    Owner = owner;
                    Show();
                }
            };
```

I know that `+= is for AddHandler owner.IsVisibleChanged, AdressOf (delegate??)`, so, which is the equivalent for that part?

**Thanks in advance.**

**PD:** I don't enough money for *buy* **.NET Reflector** :( And I wasted the trial.

Comment: There are free decompilers also. [Jetbrains DotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) and [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) for example..

Comment: Wait, are you translating code into C# (like your question says), or into VB.NET (like your question title says)?

Comment: Sorry, I misstyped it, I'm translating C# into VB.NET

Comment: Then please see [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10178159/743382). Despite the fact that the answer there is not accepted, I believe it is correct and also answers your question.

Comment: For those people that wants more reputation (up votes) check my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23310308/value-of-type-typename1-cannot-be-converted-to-typename2-using-a-structu

Comment: @user3286975 The one titled "value-of-type-typename1-cannot-be-converted-to-typename2-using-a-struct" but which you have now removed?

Comment: I solved it, it was only a bad sensitive case mathod problem...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two parts here.

1. Anonymous methods. `delegate` in C# roughly corresponds to an anonymous `Sub` in VB here.
2. Adding event handlers. `+=` in C#, `AddHandler` in VB.

Putting it together:

```
AddHandler owner.IsVisibleChanged, _
    Sub()
        …
    End Sub
```

Incidentally, the `AddressOf` operator you’ve mentioned is used in VB to refer to a (non-anonymous) method without calling it. So you would use it here if you would refer to an existing, named method rather than an anonymous method.

Comment: Thanks! You was quickly! :D