# Not sure how this c# event handling with lambdas work, can someone explain it to me please?

Tags: c#

I was looking for a way to convert vb event handling to c# since i am implementing something and, after reading this post ( [How do I Convert from Anonymous Event Handlers in C# to VB.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178159/how-do-i-convert-from-anonymous-event-handlers-in-c-sharp-to-vb-net)), i tried to copy the lambda structure, and somehow it worked, but i have NO IDEA. How it does, can someonoe please explain it to me? 
Or at least guide me to a link for a tutorial or something that helps me understand whats going on in here... 
I mean, i can get out with this since it, somehow, worked, but i want to understand whats going on rather than just, "get the job done".

```
Class.Event += Class.Delegate((sometext)) => {eventhandlemethod(sometext);});
eventhandlemethod(string s)
{
   MessageBox.Show(s);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure what you are unclear about?

Comment: Lambdas as simply a way to make Anonymous Functions. Nothing more, nothing less. However this does seem like a odd Event. Normally the arguments for events are "object sender" and "SpecificEventArgumentSubclass arg". This one seemns to take a string instead?

Comment: Yeah, this event was made by the guy before me, and im having some problems getting how he had things done...
Part of my question is that this code didnt work :
'code'Class.Event + Class.Delegate(eventhandlemethod());
eventhandlemethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("something here that gives me an alert");
}'code'

Comment: Your problem does not seem to stem from the anonymous function, but from a custom event someone else created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with VB.NET but an anonymous Function or Action as it would be in the case of an Eventhandler is basically just a short form of writing.

But what is the line

```
Class.Event += Class.Delegate((sometext) => {eventhandlemethod(sometext);});
```

telling you?

1. You have an Event, and you add the handler (obviously).
2. You have added an anonymous method as Eventhandler and created a Delegate from it.

   ```
   Class.Delegate(<anoymous method, matching the siganture of the handler>);
   ```
3. Your anonymous method looks like this

   ```
   (sometext) => {eventhandlemethod(sometext);}
   ```

This anonymous method (short lamba) consists of two parts

```
siganture => body
```

In Your case the signature gets eh "sometext". Derived from the rest of your code, this seems to be a string. And since eventhandlers always have void as return value, your method, would you have written a normal method, would look like this:

```
private void (string sometext)
{
}
```

which is basically, what your eventhandlemethod looks like. You could write this lambda like this as well.

```
(string sometext) => {eventhandlemethod(sometext);}
```

This shows you the expected intput type. But you can ommit this usually.

So just as goodie: you could have written

1. with a "normal" method, since you already have it

   ```
   Class.Event += Class.Delegate(eventhandlemethod);
   ```
2. with a lambda

   ```
   Class.Event += Class.Delegate(sometext => MessageBox.Show(sometext));
   ```

if you have multiple input variables, put them in brackets

```
(string s, int i, bool b) => Console.WriteLine($"{s}:{i}:{b}");
```

and of course, you can ommit the types as well leaving you:

```
(s, i, b) => Console.WriteLine($"{s}:{i}:{b}");
```

I hope i could clarify it a bit for you.

Comment: Yes, its a nice explanation, thanks, and i will be sure to use this answer as future reference!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Always glad to help.